# Не могу сохранить файл на амазон-с3

Tags: python, django, heroku

Использую джанго. Разместил приложение на хероку. Настроил для сохранения на амазоне

[image: here I send form]

[image: here I get my q.docx]

Photo 1: Загружаемый в форму xlsx успешно отправляется на амазон)

Photo 2 > 1: То же самое хочу и со сгенерированным docx файлом. Но его сохраняет во временной папке медиа на хероку

Если указать абсолютный путь
'path = settings.MEDIA_URL + q.name ...'
На фото 2 - это не работает. Ведь указывается относительный

Помогите советом. Спасибо

P.S. функция 'create_docx()' не может вернуть 'doc'. Получаю ошибку 'Document() file not __committed()'

Comment: Здесь вопросы задают на русском

Comment: @Sublihim исправил)

Comment: Не используйте картинки для кода. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте код как текст с форматированием.